# Populate asp.net treeview Node on selected

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I am populating asp.net treeview with database table. I am trying to populate a node when its click from database table, I tried what I can google but I am not getting it. please help

> - Root
>
>   - Fruits
>   - Meat
>   - Beverage - if someone click Beverage I want to connect to database and get a list of all and display them under Beverage

**To**

> - Root
>
>   - Fruits
>   - Meat
>   - Beverage
>   - - Alcoholic beverages
>   - - Non-alcoholic beverages

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually take advantage of native treenode functionality to write your Ajax type behaviour.

There are two TreeNode node properties you can take advantage of:

*PopulateOnDemand*: Set this property of each TreeNode to the value true for that you want to have a lazy loading of it's child-nodes.

*OnTreeNodePopulate*: This is a property of the TreeView in which you have to define the method that is called when expanding a TreeNode.

Take advantage of these and put your DB call (or cached value lookup) in the method defined by OnTreeNodePopulate.

Once done, it should work really great (and efficient).

[Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate.aspx#Y342) to the MS documentation relating to it (pretty good example)

Comment: Thanks can you please put an example.

Comment: Moksha, MS actually does a decent job of documenting this one, I've added a link above.